# Angular : Datepipe is showing date as '01/01/0001' when trying to bind NULL data from Database

Tags: angular

Do angular by default bind '01/01/0001' if we try to bind with NULL date value from database, when using DatePipe?

Comment: This question is not a good question. It seems like the answer to your question is just "YES".

Answer (score 1):

Date pipe is used to format a date value according to locale rules.

`{{ date_value | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}`

Therefore, if you set date_value to null; nothing will be displayed in your view.